# Thymeleaf th:each adding coma between elements

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have collection `X`

I iterate through it and write it like that:

```
<span th:each="a, stat : ${X}"
      th:text="${X[__${stat.index}__].someProperty} + ','">
</span>
```

my other try was:

```
<span th:each="a, stat : ${X}" th:for="|a${stat.index}|"
      th:text="${X[__${stat.index}__].someProperty} + ','">
</span>
```

unfortunately the output is the same.

the output in the span is:

```
test1, test2, test3,
```

I want the output to be:

```
test1, test2, test3
```

without the comma at the end. How can I achieve that?

**Solution:**

1. Beware of The value of attribute `th:text` associated with an element type `span` **must not contain the '<' character**.

Code:

```
<span th:each="a, stat : ${X}"
      th:text=" ${X[__${stat.index}__].someProperty} +  (${stat.size-1 > stat.index}? ',':'') ">
</span>
```

Comment: I don't know thymeleaf but can't you add a condition and check for first/last element? (Ofc if you check for first then you'd add the comma before the new element if it's not the first.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that in Thymeleaf that's why i ask

Comment: Have a look here (top result of a quick search): http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: Yeah i saw that, but my case is more difficult, we need to check e.g if it is last index, and if it is then don't add. There are many simple examples out there.

Comment: Try to adapth the examples (understand them first), e.g. would something like this work? `(${stat.index > 0}? ',':'') +  ${X[__${stat.index}__].someProperty}` (add the comma before the new element if the index is greater than 0).

Comment: Thank you very much Sir it works :)
output is:  `test1 ,test2 ,test3`
so now i have to do it
`test1, test2, test3`

Answer (score 31):

Thymeleaf has an iteration property `last` see the documentation here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status

use

```
<span th:each="a, iterStat : ${X}" th:text="!${iterStat.last} ? ${a} + ',': ${a}"></span>
```

Comment: You have omitted "$" sign after "!". It should be !${iterStat.last}

Comment: For Spring Boot, is there a cleaner way to do this? Like putting it in a Formatter or something?

Comment: @DavidTroyer sure there are multiple ways to do it. But you are manipulating the collection for the view. Doing it in the HTML allows you to manipulate the collection in the view.

Comment: my intellij idea highlighted this syntax as an error, so I changed it like this and it worked:
th:text="${!iterStat.last} ? ${a} + ',': ${a}"