# How to display a collection in a single cell instead of creating a column for every element?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I try to display a collection in a single cell, but instead it creates a column for every element.

I tried many variations with HTML combined with Thymeleaf attributes, but I don't know how to display a single cell with a text for th:each loop

```
<tr th:each="employee : ${allEmployees}">
    <td th:text="${employee.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${employee.firstName}"></td>
    <td th:text="${employee.lastName}"></td>
    <td th:text="${employee.position}"></td>
    <td th:text="${employee.salary}"></td>
    <td th:text="${employee.supervisorId}"></td>
<!--Here-->
    <td th:each="team : ${employee.teams}" th:text="${team.name}"></td>
</tr>
```

I expect something like **|| Technical Architecture, Mobile ||** but I keep getting **|| Technical Architecture || Mobile ||** etc. (don't mind a coma and a space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instructing Thymeleaf to create `<td>` tags for each team.  Instead, you can create one `<td>` tag and iterate within it:

```
<tr th:each="employee : ${allEmployees}">
    <td th:text="${employee.id}">[id]</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.firstName}">[first]</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.lastName}">[last]</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.position}">[position]</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.salary}">[salary]</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.supervisorId}">[supervisor id]</td>
<!--Here-->
    <td>
        <th:block th:each="team : ${employee.teams}">
          <span th:text="${team.name}" tag="remove">[team name]</span>
        </th:block>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If you need commas within your list, you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087491/thymeleaf-theach-adding-coma-between-elements).